# Wordpress multisite + multilingual on subdomains

Tags: wordpress, subdomain, multilingual

I have a website, using the latest wordpress version, in one language and hosted on a `lang.domain.com` sub-domain.

Now I build the english (and main) version that will be hosted on the main domain (`www.domain.com/domain.com`)

The sites are currently hosted on a different folders and are completely "stand-alone" systems.

I want them to be integrated under the same platform/folder and serving a multilingual requests, using sub domains.

My questions are:

1. Where to start?
2. What are the limitations?
3. Any thoughts to keep in mind?
4. What other questions should I ask? :)

My knowledge in wordpress is basic (themes editing, some functions..), no problem with PHP and MySql.

thanks

### edit

Found this ( http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network ) , of-course, and yet - please give me some insights

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of re-creating whole site again you have to use a WPML Plugin then it add some flag as per language to your site, where ever you want them, Alternate option you can also use Google Translator for translate your site into any language. Like i use Google Translator in one of [mine projects](http://ramp1885.com)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to show different content on the same domain you can use qTranslate wordpress plugin. Here you can create lang.mydomain.com or mydomain.com/lang or mydomain.com?lang=us. these are the three ways to display the website.